# AngularJS not running in Flask application

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, angularjs, flask

I am following this simple tutorial for creating a pinterest clone.
http://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2013/12/video-pycharm-web-magic-building-a-pinterest-clone/

I'm having trouble getting Angular to work.

html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Pin Clone</title>
</head>
<body ng-app1="app1" ng-controller="AppCtrl as app1">

{{ app1.message }}

<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="js/app1.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

app1.js code:

```
var app1 = angular.module("app1", []);

app1.controller("AppCtrl", function () {
    var app1 = this;
    app1.message = "not working"
})
```

When I reload the page I simply get to see the text:
{{ app1.message }}
This is in the browser.

Console states this on reload:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Jun/2014 12:59:50] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Jun/2014 12:59:50] "GET /bower_components/angular/angular.js HTTP/1.1"     304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Jun/2014 12:59:50] "GET /js/app1.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
```

This is on Ubuntu 14.04. I'm using Bower to install Angular into the project.

AngularJS version 1.2.17

Bower 1.3.4

node version v0.10.28

npm version 1.4.9

Project Folders:

[image: folders]

Edit 1, Flask Code in Home_Site.py:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.restless.manager import APIManager
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, Text

# instantiating Flask
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='')
# setting the SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI to the pin database
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///pin.db'

# setting an instance of SQLAlchemy
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

# creates a database model with an id, title, image
class Pin(db.Model):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column(Text, unique=False)
    image = Column(Text, unique=False)

db.create_all()

# automatically creates an api for the pins in the db
# api stands for application programming interface
api_manager = APIManager(app, flask_sqlalchemy_db=db)
api_manager.create_api(Pin, methods=['GET', 'POST', 'DELETE', 'PUT'])

# type route and hit tab to create this
# this allows you to route to the main html file in the static folder
@app.route('/')
def index1():
    return app.send_static_file('index1.html')

# reloads the server on its own
app.debug = True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: By default Flask static resources are served from `/static/...`, not the site root. By the looks of it, that is how the tutorial also sets it up. Are you certain that `/bower_components/angular/angular.js` is not a 404? The `js` folder I'd expect to *also* live under the `static` folder, and use the same prefix.

Comment: Martijn, thanks for replying. I went to run this again to inspect if I get a 404. I get one when the browser initially loads the page     127.0.0.1 - - [07/Jun/2014 21:09:26] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -   I do not know what this is referencing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your `ngApp` declaration:

```
<body ng-app1="app1" ng-controller="AppCtrl as app1">
```

should be:

```
<body ng-app="app1" ng-controller="AppCtrl as app1">
```

(Note the lack of `1` in the `ng-app` declaration.)

Comment: Wow. Thanks man I was going to lose my mind over that. This ended up working. The web page now states, "not working".

Answer (score 1):

You need to load your static resources through the `/static` route:

```
<script src="/static/bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/app1.js"></script>
```

This also means you need to move your `js` folder into the `static` folder of your project.

Comment: Martijn, thanks again. Unfortunately I can confirm that the js folder was in the static folder. This is also the case with index1.html. I tried adding /static to the src string. Unfortunately this has no effect.

Comment: @asarenski: right, I found the screenshot somewhat ambiguous. You appear to load the homepage from `/` however, not from `/static/index1.html`. You may want to detail your Flask setup.